# Azure DevOps - The time a WorkItem spends in specific columns on the kanban board

Tags: azure, azure-devops, odata, devops

I would like to report about the days features spend in each column of our kanban-board.

So for an example output I want, we have a kanban with columns:

```
Funnel           --> Workitem X spend 10 days in here
Analyzing        --> Workitem X spend 13 days in here
Backlog          --> Workitem X spend  3 days in here
Implementing     --> Workitem X spend 11 days in here
Done             --> Workitem X spend 50 days in here
```

So far I tried with

- Analytic Views: There is no BoardColumn that can be added to the output fields
- OData: Found a way to get the column-value (BoardLocation), based on the current WorkItem state
- OData: WorkItemSnapshot(to get Historic Data) does not support BoardLocation.

Do you guys know of any way that I can retrieve historic data on features and their BoardColumns?

thanks in advance,
Joost

Comment: I would suggest two solutions to this, I am not writing an answer as there may be a more correct way of dealing with:
1) Query the work item API as many times you want (as granular you want to be): [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/get%20work%20item?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0). This may be more expensive depending on how granular you want to go. But the response contains the date and status it has, storing that elsewhere you can more or less obtain the data you need.
2) Use a trigger in logic apps (for example) for when a task is updated.

Comment: Hi Mitchell, there doesn't seem to be a way to query historic data of work items. This can be done with WorkItemSnapshot, but BoardColumn is not a queryable field.

Comment: Hi @JoostVanPoppel, how about the issue? Does the answer below resolve your question, If yes, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) , so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

We can use Rest API and power shell to do this.

1. Get all work items ID by status via [Wiql query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/wiql/query%20by%20wiql?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0).

Sample script:

```
$connectionToken="pat"
$base64AuthInfo= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($connectionToken)"))
$WorkItemQueryURL = "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/{team}/_apis/wit/wiql?api-version=6.0" 

$body =@"
{
  "query": "Select [System.Id], [System.Title], [System.State] From WorkItems Where [System.WorkItemType] = 'User Story' AND [State] = 'Closed' order by [Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority] asc, [System.CreatedDate] desc"
}
"@
$WorkItem = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $WorkItemQueryURL -ContentType "application/json" -Body $body -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -Method POST

Write-host $WorkItem.workItems.id
```

Result:

[image]

2. We can get the value of field `Microsoft.VSTS.Common.StateChangeDate` via REST API [Get Work Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/get%20work%20item?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0), It is the time when the state changes, then we can calculate how many days it has been spend in this state since the state changed to `xxx`.

Sample script:

```
Write-host $WorkItem.workItems.id

ForEach ($ID in $WorkItem.workItems.id)
{
   $WorkItemInfoURL = "https://dev.azure.com/v-viliu/test/_apis/wit/workitems/$($ID)?api-version=6.0" 

   $WorkItemDetail = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $WorkItemInfoURL -Method Get -UseDefaultCredential -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)})
   
   $StateChangeDate = $WorkItemDetail.fields."Microsoft.VSTS.Common.StateChangeDate"

   Write-host "Work item ID: $ID and StateChangeDate is $StateChangeDate"

}
```

Result:

[image]

3. Calculate how many days it has been spend in this state since the state changed to xxx.

Sample script:

```
$current = Get-Date

$SpendDate= New-TimeSpan -Start $current -End $StateChangeDate 

Write-Output "The spend date is: $SpendDate"
```

Note: you need change the current date format, you can refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-date?view=powershell-7#examples) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Not to resurrect an old thread but, **TL;DR:** I had a similar problem and posted a solution out on my [Github](https://github.com/dcparsons/ado-workitem-kanban-history).

Vito's solution above will work for you if each of your columns has its own unique state, however it can only tell you how long the Work Item has spent in the current state based on Today.  It can't show you a historical view of Work Items moving across the board.

The solution I provided above isn't as simple as a Power Shell script that just gives you the report, it is a process for capturing the historical changes to the Kanban Column a work item is in that allows you to run a report similar to the one shown below.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    wi.WitID,
    DATEDIFF(day, wic_new.AuditCreatedDate, Coalesce(wic_prog.AuditCreatedDate, wic_released.AuditCreatedDate, GETDATE())) as DaysInNew,
    DATEDIFF(day, wic_prog.AuditCreatedDate, Coalesce(wic_released.AuditCreatedDate, GETDATE())) as DaysInProgess,
    DATEDIFF(day, wic_released.AuditCreatedDate, GETDATE()) as DaysInReleased
FROM WorkItems wi
LEFT JOIN WorkItem_ColumnHistory wic_new on (wic_new.WitID = wi.WitID AND wic_new.CurrentColumn = 'New' AND wic_new.WefColumnID LIKE '%[YOUR TEAMS WEF ID]%')
LEFT JOIN WorkItem_ColumnHistory wic_prog on (wic_prog.WitID = wi.WitID AND wic_prog.CurrentColumn = 'In Progress' AND wic_prog.WefColumnID LIKE '%[YOUR TEAMS WEF ID]%')
LEFT JOIN WorkItem_ColumnHistory wic_released on (wic_released.WitID = wi.WitID AND wic_released.CurrentColumn = 'Released' AND wic_released.WefColumnID LIKE '%[YOUR TEAMS WEF ID]%')
WHERE
wi.[State] NOT IN('Closed', 'Removed')
ORDER BY WitID ASC
```

The explanation for this query is in the ReadMe file of the linked GitHub repo so I will not repeat the explanation here. Basically though this query looks at the historical data that has been harvested from Azure DevOps and then displays a result set that shows how long a Work Item has existed in each column of your Kanban board.