# Azure DevOps, Display Days in Column value on Sprint Taskboard

Tags: azure-devops

I want to display 'Days in Column' on the Task cards on my team's Sprint Taskboard.

I have searched high and low in Azure DevOps doc and elsewhere but can't find any mention of this. This extremely helpful feature exists in Jira so I can't imagine is doesn't exist in Azure DevOps.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

From the Jira doc I can see Days in column is to display how many days an issue has been in the board columns. I'm afraid currently there's no such built-in feature in Azure DevOps.
But I do find an existing suggestion ticket on this feature: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Days-in-Column-indicator-for-Boards/900727?ftype=idea&q=days+in+cloumn
It is recommended for you to add your vote directly at the above linked feedback. Voting helps increase the priority of the issue by consolidating customer impact under one feedback. Please keep track of this progress via the link above. Currently as a workaround, you could check the answer in this ticket: [Azure DevOps - The time a WorkItem spends in specific columns on the kanban board](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64262879/azure-devops-the-time-a-workitem-spends-in-specific-columns-on-the-kanban-boar) to see if it could help.

Answer (score 0):

As [Evelyn Chen-MSFT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18846798/evelyn-chen-msft) has noted, there is no such built-in feature in Azure DevOps so upvoting that idea is definitely worth doing.

One workaround to this that my team uses is to use the Styles option for the Taskboard and color cards based on their Changed Date field relative to @Today. This does help to quickly spot tasks that have been left on the board and are not being worked on.

[taskboard styles using changed date field relative to @Today](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s90aQ.jpg)